# ImageMagickで複数画像を一気にリサイズしたい

Tags: imagemagick

フォルダ内に下記のような連番画像があります。

myimg_01.png
myimg_02.png
...
myimg_28.png

これらをImageMagickを使って一括で高さを 168px に変換したいです。幅はアスペクト比を保持したまま縮小させたいです。

変換した結果はそれぞれのファイルに上書きするか、出力先のフォルダに同名のファイルで保存したいです（後で名前変更をしたくない）。

どのようなコマンドになるのでしょう？

Answer (score 2):

自己解決しました。

```
mogrify -resize x168 *.png
```

↑カレントディレクトリ内の全てのPNG画像を高さ168pxにリサイズする。元のファイルを変更します。

参考：http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php

Answer (score 2):

すでに解決された様ですが、出力先のディレクトリに同名のファイルで保存する場合には `-path` オプションを使います。

```
$ mogrify -path output_dir -resize x168 *.png
```

当然ですが、`output_dir` はディレクトリとして存在していて、かつ書き込み可能(writable)である必要があります。